# Bricked chinese android

Tags: adb, 4.2-jelly-bean, unbricking, shell

Recently I edited `build.prop` of my *Note 3* smn9006 clone with mtk6572 for enabling navigation bar, i.e `qemu.hw.mainkeys=0` and restarted. Nothing happened.

Then again I tried to enable navigation bar with `ro.show.navigationbar=0`, restarted, and struck on boot logo.

When I wiped cache and data, boot logo gets inverted and still strucks on boot animation. When I tried to pull `build.prop` via adb side load it says `error:closed`.

- My device is detected as `012345678ABCDEF sideload`.
- I do *not* have a Custom Recovery installed
- Unfortunately, I neither have a backup of the unmodified `build.prop`

Comment: Did you make a backup of the file? Can you still boot into recovery mode?

Comment: i dont have the backupbut yes i can get to the screen where android logo comes with exclamation mark also when i type adb devices in cmd it detectes as 0123456789ABCDEF sideload

Comment: If you don't have the backup, that might leave you with the option to flash a ROM. Or, with some luck, to try reverting your changes via ADB.

Comment: will you please help me in that

Comment: Not sure I can (I don't know that device). But could you please [edit] your question to also include the Android version running, and whether you have a *custom recovery* installed? These facts are needed to chose the right approach.

Comment: i just hard bricked it,are their chances of recovery.my phone specs are galaxy note 3 smn9006,mtk6572 1.3 ghz dual core,jelly bean,256mb ram,500mb internal memory. i dont have custom recovery installed.

Comment: I've just [edit]ed the question for you and integrated the facts collected in the comments above. With no custom recovery, and no backup of the modified file, I'm afraid all that's left to you is to re-flash your device. Hopefully you can find a ROM on the manufacturers site. Alternatively, check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) Installation instructions are usually found along the download. Sorry, but I'm afraid there's not more that I can do for you.